# 500 error in Console, but nothing in Network

Tags: ajax, http, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools, I'm getting a 500 error in the Console tab, for a GET request:

[image]

But in the Network tab, I don't see that request; I only see a POST request for the same page, with a 200 status:

[image]

Shouldn't I be seeing the SplitShip.aspx GET request in the Network tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be seeing the SplitShip.aspx GET request in the Network tab?

You should of course, but maybe this request has been made using an AJAX call or something. So make sure you apply proper filter to your `Network` tab by selecting **All**:

[image]

This way Chrome will show **All** requests being sent to the server, including XHR ones. Are you seeing the smoking gun now?

Comment: Well duh. You're absolutely right, that was it. Thanks! (now, to delete or not to delete my question...)